# In Scala 3, how to define unapply method to extract type argument in pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-3, type-constructor

So I found some esoteric code when upgrading an old Scala 2 library, the gist of it looks like this:

```scala
object MatchExtractTypeArg {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

  def mapType(k: TypeTag[_], v: TypeTag[_]) = {

    (k, v) match {
      case (k: TypeTag[a], v: TypeTag[b]) =>
        implicit val kkk = k
        implicit val vvv = v
        implicitly[TypeTag[Map[a, b]]]
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val t1 = implicitly[TypeTag[Int]]
    val t2 = implicitly[TypeTag[String]]

    val r = mapType(t1, t2)
    println(r)
  }
}
```

the pattern matching `case (k: TypeTag[List[a]], v: TypeTag[List[b]])` is fairly difficult to understand. after some investigation, I could only speculate that the following unapply function was used on `k & v` to determine type `a & b`:

```scala
    // (in scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag definition)
    def unapply[T](ttag: TypeTag[T]): Option[Type] = Some(ttag.tpe)
```

After Scala 3 upgrade, the above code should becomes:

```
object MatchExtractTypeArg {

  def mapType(k: Typeable[_], v: Typeable[_]) = {

    (k, v) match {
      case (k: Typeable[a], v: Typeable[b]) =>
        given kk: Typeable[a] = k
        given vv: Typeable[b] = v
        summon[Typeable[Map[a, b]]]
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val t1 = summon[Typeable[Int]]
    val t2 = summon[Typeable[String]]

    val r = mapType(t1, t2)
    println(r)
  }
}
```

It apparently compiles without a problem, but when trying to figure out its mechanism, I found that the `unapply` method being defined under Typeable has an entirely different signature, and can't extract any type argument.

Am I not upgrading code properly? How could it be possible that the new extractor still works in Scala 3?

Comment: You didn't provide the code how `mapType` was used in your Scala 2 project and how those places (using `mapType`) are now rewritten in Scala 3. Without such information it's pointless to guess how to rewrite `mapType` itself. Who knows, maybe it's not needed any more at all. Please provide  the code in question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a mistake in copying code, my previous example doesn't compile. This has been corrected (with a short main function to demonstrates their purpose)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't explain how `mapType` was used in Scala 2 project (so it's not clear how to rewrite it in Scala 3 because it's not clear what you're going to achieve). There is no problem to print `TypeTag[Map[Int, String]]` directly. How did you actually use `mapType`?

Comment: By the way, `Typeable` is not a replacement for `TypeTag`, it's more like `ClassTag` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/GXxoG6gjQMKP6YAWgbKgKA

Comment: By the way, from `ClassTag` (`Typeable`?) one can construct `DeepClassTag` https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38740/files